# React-router v04 nested routes

Tags: react-router, nested-routes, react-router-dom

Is this how I should using `react-router` and nested routes in `react-router-dom`?

This code is working but I didn't fully understand the documentation so I want to be sure.

```
main.js:
const main = (props)=>(
  <Header/>
  {props.children}
);

app.js

const app = () => (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/main" children={(props) => (
      <Main {...props}>
        <Route path="section1" component={section1Component} />
        <Route path="section2" component={section2Component} />
      </Main>
    )} />
  </Router>
);
```